# How to use a single object in multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, share

I want to use a single object in multiple threads using c++. I know from java that threads share all variables, but it seems that in c++ it is different.

I have the following structure to store the date

```
Class Flow: has multiple integers
Class UE: has a list<Flow*>
Class FlowTable: has a map<int,UE*>
```

Now have two threads(Objects: InOutReader and OutInReader), each of them has a FlowTable* and shall read and/or insert data to the FlowTable.

in the main() of my starter I call new FlowTable(), create the threaded objects and give the FlowTable* to them using a setter. But in the end it looks like that the two threads work with different FlowTable objects.

```
class InOutReader{
public:

start(){

while(true){
//read data from somewhere(tap-interface1)
//extract address from ip packet and tcp/udp header etc
Flow* myflow = new Flow(IPsrc,IPdest);
this->myflowTable->insertFlow(myflow);
}
}
}

class OutInReader{
public:
start(){
while(true){
//read data from somewhere(tap-interface1)
//extract address from ip packet and tcp/udp header etc
Flow* myflow = new Flow(IPsrc,IPdest);
this->myflowTable->existsFlow(myflow);// should return true if a flow with the same data was inserted before
}
}
}
```

main programm
    FlowTable* myflowTable;

```
startThreadOne(){
InOutReader ior = InOutReader();
ior.setFlowTable(myFlowTable);
ior.start();
}

startThreadtwo(){
InOutReader oir = InOutReader();
oir.setFlowTable(myFlowTable);
oir.start();
}

void main(){
myFlowTable = new FlowTable();
std::thread t1 = std::thread(startThreadOne);
std::thread t2 = std::thread(startThreadtwo);

t1.join();
t2.join();
}
```

What I have to do to use the same FlowTable Object in multiple threads?

Comment: you need to use shared memory or pipes

Comment: It is not that different. `std::thread`s are still lightweight processes sharing the same memory space. What you need in that case is to synchronize all access to `FlowTable`.

Comment: The information you have provided does not seem sufficient to tell where your problem is.  If you pass two threads a pointer to the same object, then they can share it (hope for proper synchronization).  Btw, what does `start()` do?  is this your long-running task?

Comment: @SQL.injection Nonsense. Since when shared memory is needed to share object instances in c++?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where the threads access any global variables, so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @SQL.injection pipes between the same process? That's interesting...

Comment: Actually,why did you (1) make `myFlowTable` a global variable, (2) make `myFlowTable` a pointer to an object on the free store (that you never `delete`) and (3) still pass it to the threads when they could just access the global variable?  Also, `main` must return `int`.

Comment: @5gon12eder It's true that `myFlowTable` could be a local variable in `main`.  But there's really no point in deleting it; only one is ever allocated, and it's used up until the end of the program.  (And IMHO, passing it to the threads is a lot cleaner than having them access a global variable.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree that a global variable should not be used but given that he is using a setter, it is not only bad style but also useless.  About the missing `delete`: True, if `FlowTable`'s destructor does not have any desirable side effects.  I don't know whether it has in this situation.

Comment: @5gon12eder I've not yet figured out what he's talking about with regards to the "setter".  The usual meaning for "setter" is a class member function which sets an attribute, but I don't see anything along those lines in his code.  With regards to the dynamic allocation: if `FlowTable` is a concrete class, and nothing but a wrapper for an `std::map`, I'd certainly agree that it should be a local variable in `main`.  If it's something more complicated, there may be reasons to make it abstract, and use a factory function to construct an instance of a derived class.

Comment: @Sebastian I still cannot make sense of your updated question except that I can tell pretty sure that you are using way too many `new`s and way too little indentation.  Please provide a [minimal self-consistent example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I just want that both threads have access to the same FlowTable object, because its the central object I am storing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make heads or tails of your explication, but if you want to have the two threads sharing the same dynamically allocated `FlowTable`, the solution in C++ is incredibly simple:

```
int
main()
{
    FlowTable* sharedFlowTable = new FlowTable();
    std::thread t1( startThread1, sharedFlowTable );
    std::thread t2( startThread2, sharedFlowTable );
    //  ...
}
```

Then declare `startThread1` and `startThread2` to take a `FlowTable*` as argument.  (This is a lot simpler than in Java; in Java, where you'd have to define one class per thread, deriving from `Runnable`, and give each class a constructor which took a `FlowTable`, and copied it to a member variable so that the `run` function could find it.)

EDIT:

Of course, if the value pointed to by `sharedFlowTable` really is a `FlowTable`, and no inheritance and factory functions are involved, you could just make it a local variable in `main`, rather than a pointer, and pass `&sharedFlowTable` to the threads.  This would be even simpler, and more idiomatic in C++.  (And  I have to thank @5gon12eder for pointing this out.  Embarrassingly, because I'm usually the one arguing against dynamic allocation unless it is necessary.)

Comment: OP seems to have a Java background but the C++ way would be to use `FlowTable ft {}; std::thread t1 {startThread1, &ft}; std::thread t2 {startThread2, &ft}; …`.

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes, and I've updated to reflect this (based on your comments to the question---thanks).  On the other hand, it's possible that his example is simplified, and that in the actual code, `FlowTable` is abstract, and he calls a factory function to get it.  (From his description, I don't think this would be appropriate, if I've understood the semantics correctly.  But there are certainly cases where it would be appropriate.)

Comment: Sure, but if Java programmers learn C++, 99 % of the time, they don't really need to use `new`.

Comment: @5gon12eder Which is something I'm usually the one saying:-). 99% of the time I see people recommending smart pointers, the correct response is not to use dynamic allocation to begin with.  I totally agree that dynamic allocation should only be used when there is a valid reason for it.

Comment: are the following two things really the same?

`FlowTable* sharedFlowTable = new FlowTable();
thread(startThread1, sharedFlowTable );`

and 
`FlowTable sharedFlowTable = new FlowTable();
thread(startThread1, &sharedFlowTable );`

because I get different results. for the first thing is get segmentation fault(probably my mistake up to now their is no synchronisation)

while for the second I get the same result as before

Comment: @Sebastian The second isn't legal, and shouldn't compile.  Since the constructor of `FloatTable` doesn't take any arguments, the second should be `FloatTable sharedFloatTable; std::thread t1( startThread1, &sharedFloatTable );`.  The whole point here is that there is no dynamic allocation (so no `new`).  (And you need a name for the thread object.)  And of course, if there's no synchronization, it's all undefined behavior, and no one can draw any conclusions.

Comment: You are right I meant this both 
`FlowTable* sharedFlowTable = new FlowTable(); thread(startThread1, sharedFlowTable );`
`FlowTable sharedFlowTable =  FlowTable(); thread(startThread1, &sharedFlowTable );`
The following will also work? The implicit call of the constructor confuses my every time.
`FlowTable sharedFlowTable;`

Comment: It the type has a user defined constructor (any constructor), it is impossible to create an instance of it without the constructor being called.  (That's really no different than in Java, except that in Java, the _only_ way to get an instance of a user defined type is to dynamically allocate it with `new`.)  But you must declare a variable (with a name) for each of the threads.  The line `std::thread( startThread1, &sharedFlowTable );` will construct a temporary instance of the thread, then destruct it at the end of the full expression.  This in turn will cause the program to crash.